# Why did Antiochus IV of the Seleucids work so hard to keep Coele-Syra from Ptolemy VI of Eygpt?

Tags: ancient-history

In 168 BC when Antiochus IV king of the Seleucid Empire marched on Alexandria to make sure that Ptolemy VI of Egypt would not try to take back the land that Antiochus' ancestors had gained for Egypt, what motives other than the want of more land and power did Antiochus have for doing this?

In other words, was there something in Coele-Syria that would give Antiochus more power over Egypt?

Comment: Syria was Antiochus' access to the Mediterranean Sea.

Comment: @Oldcat Where can I find a source for this info?

Comment: You can look at a globe. Selucids had Iran Iraq. Syria is between them and the sea.

Comment: If a country is attacked it usually strikes back, what is so special about this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syria is right on his doorsteps. It's a natural target of expansion for him. It gave him a connection to the rest of the mediterranean world.